# I can save the image view and the sticker together

Tags: ios, swift, image

I added a sticker to image view.

So I saved it with the following source.

```
 imageView.addSubview(StickerView[0])

    // Create the image context to draw in
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((imageView.bounds.size), false, 0)

    // Get that context
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    // Draw the image view in the context
    imageView.layer.render(in: context!)

    // You may or may not need to repeat the above with the imageView's subviews
    // Then you grab the "screenshot" of the context
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    // Be sure to end the context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    CustomPhotoAlbum.sharedInstance.save(image: image! )
```

Well saved. However, the black background on both sides of the image is saved as well. Can I save only part of the image except the black background?

This is saved together. I want to save only the part of the image except this one.

Comment: What black background are you talking about?

Comment: On iOS, imageview usually shows a black background in the margin of the image.

Comment: Then don't draw the image view, draw the image view's image.

Comment: Does that save the sticker with addsubview in imageview? I would like to save up to the sticker view of addsubview in the image view.

Comment: After creating your `UIImage`, learn how to use `CGImage.cropping(to:rect)`.

Comment: If you need help, ask something specific and I'll try to answer. I think I commented on a question you asked yesterday. Your need is similar to something I'm working on. (But... my app uses `CIImage`, which is CoreImage.) At some point though I have (a) a `GLKView` - for your purposes analogous to a `UIImageView` - with one or more `UIViews` as subviews, (b) a need to create a new "image" - in this case a `CIImage` but I believe it's inconsequential for you - of everything,.... *image* involved, keeping in mind that the actual "view" is in aspect fit...

Comment: ...and (c) a need to *both* scale things *and* use the frames of all the subviews *and* crop the resulting image - be it `UIKit`, `GLKit`, or `CoreImage` - to the image displayed with borders because my view is "square" and the image isn't.

Comment: I got a hint and figured it out. This problem is solved. Thank you very much.